# android:ellipsize="marquee" not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview, marquee

i have tried to use marquee but its not working,please help to solve this

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_from"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#343d43"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text_to"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/label_from"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label_from" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**`android:singleLine`** is **<s>Deprecated</s>**. Use

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:focusable="true"
```

**FYI**

You should add [**`setSelected`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelected(boolean))

> Changes the selection state of this view. A view can be selected or
>   not. Note that selection is not the same as focus.

```
TextView text_fromOBJ=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_from);
text_fromOBJ.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: sir he also need to add this `textView.setSelected(true)`

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes sir.

Comment: tnx it's solve to add `textView.setSelected(true)`

Comment: @GautamSurani indeed. For good approach remove `android:singleLine`

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

you need add this lines in java

```
TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_from);
txtView.setSelected(true);
```